# Difference of decimal numbers with another base

Tags: python

I am using Python. I have several pairs of numbers and I want to find their difference, but their base is on 42. For example,

```
5.39->5.40->5.41->5.42->6.00
```

So, 10.38 with 10.24 has 0.14, but 10.41 with 11.02 has 0.03

Is there any way to do this with Python? The only way I can imagine is to take several IF for every case.

Example of my data:

```
[3.08,3.15] --> 0.07
[4.39,5.10] --> 0.13
[13.00,14.12] --> 1.12
[40.42,41.01] --> 0.02
```

Comment: Example is not clear. What are the pairs here?

Comment: You also have an odd number of digits.

Comment: So you want to compare the fractional part only to see how close they are to 42?

Comment: Question has been updated with more examples :)

Comment: Your question is still not clear. What does "base is on 42" mean?  What does "10.38 with 10.24 has 0.14" mean?  What is the operation you're trying to do, and what does base have to do with it?

Comment: 0.14 is how close the two numbers are.

Comment: Ok, that's normally called subtraction. How does that relate to "10.41 with 11.02 has 0.03"?

Comment: From here (5.39->5.40->5.41->5.42->6.00). You could imagine it like days of the month. Every 31 days, the month change. My data, every 42 decimals, the integer change. My english skills are low and probably I cannot describe it with terms. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this? Subtracts A from B using 0.42 as cap for decimal part.

```
base = 42
a = (5,10)
b = (4,39)

if a > b:
   b, a = a, b

overflow = int(b[1] < a[1])

c = (b[0]-a[0]-overflow, b[1]+base*overflow-a[1])
print(c)
```

Question is not very clear. Also I used tuples to avoid parsing.

Edit: added the if guard

Comment: The problem here is in this example a = (4,20), b = (4,10). It supposed to print 0.10 but it prints (-1, 32)

Comment: Compare the numbers and subtract smaller from larger.

Comment: You can use integers by multiplying by 100 before you start, then divide the result by 100.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there cant be an element 5.42 with base 42, i think the base should be 43.

I think this is it you want

```
a=11.02
b=10.41
base=43

def diff(a,b,base):
     x=int(a)*base+int(round((a%1)*100))
     y=int(b)*base+int(round((b%1)*100))
     print x
     print y
     return (x-y)/base+((x-y)%base)/100.0
c=diff(a,b,base)
print c
```

Comment: `diff(6.00, 5.42)` should be 0.01, not 0.02

Comment: Eh, with base 42 it would be 0.00 and with base-43 it would be 0.01, no?

Comment: ya 42=0.00(base 42) but 42=0.42(base 43) thats what i thought.Its ok, change the base to 42 :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be overkill, but...

```
digits = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEF'

assert len(digits) == 42

def base(n, b=2, digits=digits):
    if n < 0:
        raise ValueError("no negative numbers")
    if n < b:
        return digits[n]
    res = []
    q = n
    while q:
        q, r = divmod(q, b)
        res.append(digits[r])
    return ''.join(reversed(res))


def debase(s, base=2, digits=digits):
    if not (2 <= base <= len(digits)):
        raise ValueError("base must be >= 2 and <= %d" % len(digits))
    res = 0
    for i, v in enumerate(reversed(s)):
        digit = digits.index(v)
        res += digit * (base ** i)
    return res


class Val(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = base(b, 42)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        a = self.a - other.a
        b = debase(self.b, 42) - debase(other.b, 42)
        if b < 0:
            b += 42
            a -= 1
        return Val(a, b)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Val({a}, {b})".format(a=self.a, b=debase(self.b, 42))

    def __str__(self):
        return "%d.%02d" % (self.a, debase(self.b, 42))


print Val(4,20) - Val(4,10)
# 0.10
print Val(11,2) - Val(10,41)
# 0.03
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have suggested simply setting the base parameter in [int](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int), but that only applies for numbers n in [2, 36]. Instead you can convert to and from any base with something like:

```
def frombase(numbers, n):
    return sum(float(a)*n**i for i, a in izip(count(len(numbers)-1, -1), numbers))

def tobase(number, n):
    numbers = []
    while number:
        numbers.append(int(number % n))
        number = int(number / n)
    return numbers
```

You could then produce the result per pair by doing:

```
converted = map(lambda x: frombase(str(x).split('.'), 42), numbers)
print('.'.join(tobase(abs(converted[1] - converted[0]))))
```

I'll leave it to you to generalize this into any set of symbols --> any other set of symbols.